# Double Inner Join Query of Access 2007 db in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, ms-access-2007

I'm having a problem jumping across multiple relational tables in an access 2007 database using aspx and vb.net. Sadly I have no control over 17+ table db structure or format.

The query i'm attempting to call works correctly in access but throws the following error when run through asp and vb.net.

```
No value given for one or more required parameters.
```

Tbl_A Structure:

```
ID (PK)
Device_SiteID (Linked to Tbl B)
StatusID
...
```

Tbl_B Structure

```
Device_SiteID
SiteID (Linked To Tbl_C)
...
```

Tbl_C Structure

```
SiteName
SiteID
...
```

code

```
Dim path As String = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("..\abcd\db\db.accdb")
        Dim dbCon As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+ path)
dbCon.Open()
Dim sql As String = ""
sql = "SELECT Tbl_FMOPM828.[StatusID] "
sql += "FROM Tbl_Sites "
sql += "INNER JOIN (LTbl_Device_Sites "
sql += "INNER JOIN Tbl_FMOPM828 "
sql += "ON LTbl_Device_Sites.[Device_SitesID] = Tbl_FMOPM828.[Device_SitesID]) "
sql += "ON Tbl_Sites.SitesID = LTbl_Device_Sites.SitesID "
sql += "WHERE ((Not(Tbl_FMOPM828.StatusID)=1) AND ((Tbl_Sites.SitesName)=Timbucktoo))"

Dim statusCmd As N`ew OleDbCommand(sql, dbCon)
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to enclose Timbucktoo in quotes = 'Timbucktoo'

Comment: correction, use this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx or this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx the previous example kinda sucked, and the ref for oledbcommand kinda sucks too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx and enclose above mentioned parameter in quotes ;p

Comment: ...it's always something small like this.

Thank you, the query is working now however it's returning "No data exists for the row/column." when run in access it returned several records from the DB

Comment: Give some code below (...)  and check that [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971514.aspx)

Comment: The last error was because i was referencing the reader before telling it to read. Thank you for your help, gladly i'm now onto query #3 of about 15 that i need to write/convert.